Meta Facebook Embedded Signup in Django Python
I work on a company that works with whatsapp chatbot. I created a page to make our clients signin with their facebook's business account to get permissions to send message on behalf of them. I'm implementing the embedded signup in a simple page just to get the access token. For test purposes, I created a simple backend in python to return the access token to the page.
These are the codes I have: (I just replaced the ids with xxx,yyy and zzz because I think these are not needed here)
Frontend
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        // JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
        FB.init({
          appId: "xxx", // Facebook App ID
          cookie: true, // enable cookies
          xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
          version: "v20.0", //Graph API version
        });
      };

      // Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
      (function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
          fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");

      // Facebook Login with JavaScript SDK
      function launchWhatsAppSignup() {

        // Launch Facebook login
        FB.login(
          function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
              console.log("response", response);
              const code = response.authResponse.code;

              // Make a call to the Flask server with Axios
              axios
                .post("http://localhost:5000/get-access-token", { code: code })
                .then((response) => {
                  console.log("Server response:", response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error("Error making the server request:", error);
                });
            } else {
              console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
            }
          },
          {
            config_id: "yyy", // configuration ID goes here
            response_type: "code", // must be set to 'code' for System User access token
            override_default_response_type: true, // when true, any response types passed in the "response_type" will take precedence over the default types
            extras: {
              featureType: "only_waba_sharing",
              setup: {
                solutionID: "zzz",
              },
            },
          }
        );
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url(background4.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      style="
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      "
    >
      <div
        style="
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          gap: 15px;
          padding: 25px;
          /* border: 1px solid #2a9ac1; */
          border-radius: 16px;
          /* background-color: white; */
        "
      >
        <!-- <div>
          <img src="logo-web.png" style="width: 300px" />
        </div> -->
        <div style="text-align: center">
          <button
            onclick="launchWhatsAppSignup()"
            style="
              background-color: #1877f2;
              border: 0;
              border-radius: 4px;
              color: #fff;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-weight: bold;
              height: 40px;
              padding: 0 24px;
            "
          >
            Login with Facebook
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


Backend
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/get-access-token', methods=['POST'])
def get_access_token():
    data = request.get_json()
    code = data.get('code')
    if not code:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No code provided'}), 400
    
    app_id = 'XXX'
    app_secret = 'XXX'
    
    url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&code={code}'
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(jsonify(response.json()))
        return jsonify(response.json())
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to get access token', 'details': response.json()}), response.status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)

This is working fine when I serve the front with http-server command and run the backend.
I'm using ngrok too. With it I can use the URL (with https) in my App configs in Meta' system. I put it in Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK (In Facebook Login for Business section) and in Domain manager (In App Settings -> Advanced section). Which means that when user clicks in the "Login with Facebook" button, it opens the popup. If the user closes the popup it's calling the callback in FB.login and receiving the response {authResponse: null, status: 'unknown'}, which makes the program to log in console "User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.". And if the user complete the signin it calls the backend and I receive the access token.
The problem is that when I try to "move" this code to Django, the callback function in FB.login is being called, returning {authResponse: null, status: 'unknown'} in the response when the window for signin pops up and it ignores anything I do after that (like close the window or complete the signin).
I've asked for chatGPT and in summary he suggested the following:

Add your ngrok URL to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Add the ngrok URL to CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS.

Verify SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE settings.

Set SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER to handle HTTPS proxies.

Double-check your Facebook app settings, especially the redirect URI.

Inspect the browser's network tab for more details on failed requests.


It seems Django is interfering with the login in some way, but not sure how and why.
Any ideas?
